# put a left margin on a background image

Tags: html, css

I'm a CSS fresher. What I'm trying to do is I want to lay a background image in an HTML.
My intent is I want to left margin the background image of 200px. My code is shared as below or you can check in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benmore/D5sNs/

```
    <style type="text/css">

        body{
            margin-left:200px;
            background:#5d9ab2 url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ZBLYo1oD6bM/UHox3oBICxI/AAAAAAAAAgo/yCg6TcxLeC4/s358/img_tree.png) no-repeat top left;

        }

        .container {
            text-align:center;  
            width: 100px;
        }   


    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body class="homepage">
    <div class="container">
        test
    </div>

</body>
```

My only problem is the background is staying closed to the left.
What can I do to make it starts 200px from the left edge of the page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `background-position: 200px 0;` to your `body`'s CSS

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/D5sNs/1/

The `background-position` CSS property allows you to position your background image around the container. Read more here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-position

Comment: mean a background isn't recognized as an element of body?
do I understand correctly?

Comment: The background is only a *property* of an element, it is not an element as such.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div-container, set there the background image and add this line:

left: 200px;

(for the div)

You can use span too